# Parameters for Multisig Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, remix, multisignature

I was referring to multisig smart contract posted at below URL: 
https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/wallet/wallet.sol

However, I am getting confused with some of the parameters to be passed in the contract.

For Example, I am not getting properly what needs to be passed in place of *bytes32 _operation*  in the function **hasConfirmed**.

Could someone help me out of it.? You can suggest me sample data to be passed for the parameters in each function. Any video link where anyone has worked with this contract can be helpful too(where they have worked with parameters too).

**NOTE**: I am using online solidity compiler(Remix - Solidity IDE)

Answer (score 0):

When a new transaction is submitted for execution via the following:

`function execute(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) external onlyowner returns (bytes32 _r) {`

It returns as you can see essentially a transactionID. This bytes32 ID is then used by other key holders to confirm the transaction.

*hasConfirmed* is used to check whether or not a certain transaction has already been confirmed, by passing in this transactionID.

If you are flexible as to which multisig wallet you use I would recommend this Gnosis one as being more intuitive and clear to use: https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/solidity/MultiSigWallet.sol

Comment: I am not using any wallet. I am compiling the program in Remix Solidity Compiler(via connecting with my private chain). This is quite helpful. However it will be great if you can elaborate on other parameters as well. I tried passing transaction ID but it returns false many time(not specifically execute function). I have seen people struggling to know the parameters to be passed while execution. Also i forgot to mention that i am using this contract after splitting it in parts. Like right now i am working on multiOwned part of the contract eliminating function execute.

Comment: Tried using the recommended MultiSig wallet code by you. Have a few question on that: **1.** **_uint256 address_** and **_uint256 transactionid_**, however both should be **bytes32** as per my understanding  **2.** **_confirm transaction_** function always displays gasPrice problem, please suggest if i can change it accordingly(steps would be fine for this).  **3.** It would be great if you can suggest step wise step procedure to be followed for a complete flow(For example Multisig 3 is to 3, where all three needs to confirm for complete transaction)